# Pandas groupby and correct with median in new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns, median

My dataframe look like this

```
Plate Sample LogRatio
 P1     S1     0.42
 P1     S2     0.23 
 P2     S3     0.41 
 P3     S4     0.36 
 P3     S5     0.18
```

I have calculated the median of each plate (but it's probably not the best idea to start like this)

```
grouped = df.groupby("Plate")
medianesPlate = grouped["LogRatio"].median()
```

And I want to add a column on my dataframe

```
CorrectedLogRatio = LogRatio-median(plate)
```

I suppose with :

```
df["CorrectedLogRatio"] = LogRatio-median(plate)
```

To have something like this :

```
Plate Sample LogRatio CorrectedLogRatio
 P1     S1     0.42    0.42-median(P1)   
 P1     S2     0.23    0.23-median(P1)
 P2     S3     0.41    0.41-median(P2)
 P3     S4     0.36    0.36-median(P3)
 P3     S5     0.18    0.18-median(P3)
```

But I don't know how to get the median from medianesPlates.
I tried some apply and transform functions but it doesn't work. 
Thanks for any help

Comment: What exactly does not work and what error do you get? Do you perhaps mean to use `CorrectedLogRatio = LogRatio-medianesPlate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation):

```
df['CorrectedLogRatio'] = df['LogRatio'] - df.groupby('Plate')['LogRatio'].transform('median')
```

The resulting output:

```
  Plate Sample  LogRatio  CorrectedLogRatio
0    P1     S1      0.42              0.095
1    P1     S2      0.23             -0.095
2    P2     S3      0.41              0.000
3    P3     S4      0.36              0.090
4    P3     S5      0.18             -0.090
```