# Make new column based on groupby calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas `DataFrame`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "category": ["one", "one", "one", "one", "two", "two", "two", "three", "three", "three"], 
    "value": [2, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 5, 7, 8, 6]
})

>>> df
  category  value
0      one      2
1      one      4
2      one      3
3      one      2
4      two      5
5      two      6
6      two      5
7    three      7
8    three      8
9    three      6
```

I want to calculate a new column called `normalized` by computing the median (or any other groupby operation) and subtracting it (or any other simple operation) from the corresponding values in the non-grouped `DataFrame`. In non-pandas code this is what I mean:

```py
new_column = []

# Groupby equivalent
for cat in df["category"].unique():
    curr_df = df[df["category"] == cat]
    curr_median = curr_df.median()
    
    # Calculation on groupby components
    for val in curr_df["value"]:
        normalized = val - curr_median
        new_column.append(normalized)

df["normalized"] = new_column
```

Which results in the following `DataFrame`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "category": ["one", "one", "one", "one", "two", "two", "two", "three", "three", "three"], 
    "value": [2, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 5, 7, 8, 6],
    "normalized": [-0.5, 1.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0]
})

>>> df
  category  value  normalized
0      one      2        -0.5
1      one      4         1.5
2      one      3         0.5
3      one      2        -0.5
4      two      5         0.0
5      two      6         1.0
6      two      5         0.0
7    three      7         0.0
8    three      8         1.0
9    three      6        -1.0
```

How could I write this in a nicer, pandas way? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas groupby and correct with median in new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532303/pandas-groupby-and-correct-with-median-in-new-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transform` is your friend.  I think of this as `apply` when I want to maintain the original dataframe shape.  You can use this:

```
df["normalized"] = df.value - df.groupby("category").value.transform("median")
```

output:

```
  category  value  normalized
0      one      2        -0.5
1      one      4         1.5
2      one      3         0.5
3      one      2        -0.5
4      two      5         0.0
5      two      6         1.0
6      two      5         0.0
7    three      7         0.0
8    three      8         1.0
9    three      6        -1.0
```